# Merge columns containing categories with columns containing integers

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I would like to create a correlation data between columns [like in this diagonal correlation matrix](https://seaborn.pydata.org/examples/many_pairwise_correlations.html).

My data is currently is this format:

[image]

And i need to convert it to this format:

[image]

How is this possible, merging the categories from T and G into the Sample columns?

Thanks for your help!

Edit:

`print(df.dtypes)` outputs:

```
T
int64
Group
object
Sample1
float64
Sample2
int64
Sample3
float64
dtype: object
```

`print(df.index)` outputs:

```
Int64Index([0, 1, 3, 6, 16, 18, 19, ..., 52], dtype='int64')
```

`print(type(df))` outputs:

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
```

Comment: Have you looked at [multi-indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/advanced.html)?

Comment: Yes, i was thinking about using `df.set_index(['T', 'Group'])` to iterate over the indexes and creating a new dataset with a new column for each iteration. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that your original dataframe is called df and your columns are T, G and Sample*, the following code prepare a new data frame with the desired format:

```
list_T = list(df['T'].unique())
list_G = list(df['G'].unique())
list_Samples = list(df.drop(['T', 'G'], axis = 1).columns)

cols = []
data = []
for s in list_Samples:
    for g in list_G:
        for t in list_T:
            cols.append(s + ' T' + str(t) + ' ' + g)
            data.append(list(df[s][(df['T'] == t) & (df['G'] == g)]))

df2 = pd.DataFrame(data = np.array(data).T, columns = cols)
```

Original dataframe:

[image]

Transformed dataframe:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It would be easier when you put link to data. I dont want to prescribe your data. Please try with PANDAS - Crosstab.

Comment: When i apply `pd.crosstab(df.Group, df.T, margins=True)` i get the error `TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable`

Comment: First check what type of data you have.
print(df.dtypes) and  index

Comment: end DataFrame: print(type(df))

Comment: thank you, i posted the outputs in the thread - what does it tell?